# Converting between timezones in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I am converting this time and date:

```
Thu, 31 Mar 2011 02:05:59 GMT
```

To the following time and date format:

```
Monday March 28 2011 4:48:02 PM
```

I am using the following PHP code to accomplish this, but I want to convert all time zones to PST/PDT. I looked at the PHP manual and saw this `date_default_timezone_set()` but I am not sure how to implement that into the code I have below.

```
$date = $messages[0]->CreationTime;
echo date('l F j Y g:i:s A I', strtotime($date))
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

I would not use `date_default_timezone_set` for general TZ conversions. (To clarify... if this is for display purposes, script wide, then using the default timezone is a reasonable thing to do.)

Instead, I would use something like:

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');

$date = new DateTime('Thu, 31 Mar 2011 02:05:59 GMT');
$date->setTimezone($tz);
echo $date->format('l F j Y g:i:s A I')."\n";
```

Comment: Correct, using date_default_timezone_set will change the time zone of the whole app.

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = $messages[0]->CreationTime;
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo date('l F j Y g:i:s A I', strtotime($date));
```

See [this list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php) for available timezones that get passed into the function

Comment: Here's a list of the supported arguments into date_default_timezone_set: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: changing your default timezone is a bad idea.  you should really do that sort of thing in your php.ini file.   if you change the default timezone, other dates could be affected when you arent expecting it.

Comment: @BrentLarsen Time zones should be per application not globally on the server.