# PHP - Can't set correct DateTimeZone to DateTime

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, datetime-conversion

## Background

---

I have a list of events that are set to a certain (UK) time. I want users to see the time of the event in their local time. For example: if an event starts at `20:30` UK time a user from the Netherlands should see the start time as `21:30`.

## Problem

---

I've got everything set up, and am creating new `DateTime` objects to set my events to. However, when I specify my `DateTimeZone` object it shows `+00:00` in stead of the `DateTimeZone` I have created for it. This means that the new times are incorrect. So time that were set to `20:30` UK time still roll out as `20:30` NL time in stead of `21:30`.

## Code

---

This is the code I've written. As far as I'm aware everything I'm doing is correct, but the `DateTimeZone` is still incorrect when assigned to the `DateTime` object.

The default setting:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

The code that should convert `DateTime` objects to local time:

```
$user_timezone = Helper::get_user_timezone(); //contains "Europe/Amsterdam"
foreach($events as $event){
    $timestamp = $event->getDatetime()->getTimestamp();
    $local_datetime = new DateTime('@'.$timestamp, new DateTimeZone($user_timezone));
}
```

## Input

---

I'll use the following `DateTime` object as input:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2015-02-14 19:30:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/London
)
```

## Output

---

This outputs the following `DateTime` object for me:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2015-02-14 19:30:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 1
    [timezone] => +00:00
)
```

## What have I tried

---

I've tried multiple things. Mostly it was about the order I set the `DateTimeZone`.

1. I tried creating a `DateTimeZone` before the creation of the `DateTime` object. I made sure it was a correct object and set it in the `DateTime` constructor then.
2. I tried creating a `DateTime` object first with just a timestamp as parameter, and setting the `DateTimeZone` object afterwards (I know there is/was a bug that caused some weird behaviour with setting `DateTimeZone` directly).
3. I've made sure the timezone I want to set (`Europe/Amsterdam`) is legit according to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php).

I'm starting to wonder if it's not possible to convert the date when using a `timestamp`?

I have also looked at these question for the basic gist, but they have no such problem:
 1. [Converting between timezones in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503135/converting-between-timezones-in-php)
 2. [How to convert between time zones in PHP using the DateTime class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625834/how-to-convert-between-time-zones-in-php-using-the-datetime-class)

I followed a couple more, but I can't find them at the moment.

## Question

---

Why is my `DateTime` object getting an incorrect `DateTimeZone`?

## Edit

---

After checking again that my `DateTimeZone` objects are correct I get the following:

```
DateTimeZone Object
(
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Amsterdam
)
```

But when I set it to the new `DateTime` object both the `timezone_type` and `timezone` change to:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2015-02-14 19:30:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 1
    [timezone] => +00:00
)
```

You'll notice the different `timezone_type` and `timezone`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting between timezones in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503135/converting-between-timezones-in-php)

Comment: @cmorrissey I already tried that. I even specified it in my question... The problem is not converting, but setting the `DateTimeZone`. In my opinion it's definitely not a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use method [`DateTime::setTimeZone()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

$date = new DateTime('2015-02-14 19:30:00');
print_r($date);
echo("Local time in London: ".$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n");

$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'));
print_r($date);
echo("Local time in Amsterdam: ".$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n");
```

The output of the script above:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2015-02-14 19:30:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/London
)
Local time in London: 2015-02-14 19:30:00
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2015-02-14 20:30:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Amsterdam
)
Local time in Amsterdam: 2015-02-14 20:30:00
```

If you don't want to modify the original `$date` object then you can `clone` it and modify the timezone of the clone:

```
$roDate = clone $date;
$roDate->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Bucharest'));
echo("Local time in Bucharest: ".$roDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n");
```

displays:

```
Local time in Bucharest: 2015-02-14 21:30:00
```

#### Remarks

I ran the code with PHP 5.6.6 on OSX.

The `DateTime` and related classes had a lot of bugs in their early versions (PHP 5.2, PHP 5.3). Most of them were fixed in the recent versions (but there still are some well hidden minor issues).

My suggestion is to use the most recent version of PHP you can install on your system.

Comment: Wow, okay that's weird. I did try the `setTimezone()` method, but only on the new `DateTime` object I was creating. Using it on the existing `DateTime` object gives the correct result. Some weird behaviour indeed. Just as a FYI I'm also running PHP 5.6.6 on Windows. Thanks!

Comment: There is a note on the documentation of [`DateTime::__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) that says that the **$timezone** argument is ignored when the **$time** argument is a Unix timestamp. This is the source of the strange behaviour of your code. You can still set the correct timezone (using method [`setTimeZone()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)) to the object after you create it.

Comment: What the... I seriously thought I tried that, but you're right :I Must have been sloppy on my side. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation:

[DateTime::__construct](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)

> Note:
>
> The $timezone parameter and the current timezone are ignored when the
>   $time parameter either is a UNIX timestamp (e.g. @946684800) or
>   specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00).

So, just use the "setTimezone()" solution or provide a datetime string  :)