# How we get the exist time and date of the user using php

Tags: php

i want to get the  **visitor**  **local time**  and **date** using **php**. I am try different method but failed. i am using 
     **strftime('%c')**;

Comment: why you use `strftime('%c')`?

Comment: [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php): `%C` -Two digit representation of the century (year divided by 100, truncated to an integer).

Comment: @FrayneKonok But the OP has used '%c' Preferred date and time stamp based on locale

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get client's timezone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905397/how-to-get-clients-timezone)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine a User's Timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determine-a-users-timezone)

Answer (score 1):

You can't, at least not reliably. The browser doesn't send its timezone to the server with each request.

You could look at the IP address the request came from, hope that it isn't a proxy, and use a GeoIP database to guess where the user is. From that you could extrapolate the timezone. Then you could [convert between the server's timezone and the one you think the visitor is in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503135/converting-between-timezones-in-php).

Alternatively, you could use client-side JavaScript to get the timezone from the visitor's browser.

Comment: Is it possible to get local time using [function.localtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.localtime.php)

Comment: @FrayneKonok — That gets the **server's** localtime. The server knows nothing about the browser's localtime as the answer says.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
echo "Created date is " . date("Y-m-d h:i:sa", $d);
?>
```

try this it will give you the date and time use it in a hidden field to  itget

Comment: This will give the server date and time, not the client's local date and time as required in the question.