# How to calculate timestamp from given timestamp and GMTOffset value in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone-offset, gmt, timestamp-with-timezone

Currently I am using an API for flights search that shows flight details. In API response, few dates and GMTOffset is returned. I need to convert these to Pakistan Standard Time.
API Response looks as following:

```
DepartureDateTime: 2018-11-10T14:20:00

ArrivalDateTime: 2018-11-11T07:10:00

DepartureTimeZone => "GMTOffset": -5

ArrivalTimeZone => "GMTOffset": 3
```

Kindly guide me how can I convert above date/time to Pakistan Standard Date/Time because I do not have an idea how these GMTOffset values will help me to get what I want.

Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short-order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far as a [mcve], the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. It may help to re-read [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting between timezones in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503135/converting-between-timezones-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateTimeZone](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) to set the UTC and your local [timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php), this will automatically convert UTC to your local time:

```
$utc = "2018-11-10T14:20:00";
$dt = new DateTime($utc);
$tz = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Karachi'); // or whatever zone you're after

$dt->setTimezone($tz);
echo $dt->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

Output: `10-11-2018 19:20:00`