# WooCommerce Rest API Get Orders Dates

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On the WooCommerce REST API, in what format should the dates appear? The WooCommerce website timezone is Pacific. My query returns an order prior to the dates. The order was placed on 5/7/2021 at 10:08 AM PST. My query says get sales after 5/7/21 3:37 PM UTC onwards.

Here is my URL:

https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/orders?after=2021-05-07T15:37:00Z&before=2021-05-11T22:03:12Z&per_page=50&page=3

Here is the WooCommerce version:

"wc_version": "3.9.3",
"version": "3.1.0",

Here is the order:

[image]

Comment: Default WordPress standard is UTC, Universal Time Coordinated.

Comment: You need to format the date_created once you received it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting between timezones in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503135/converting-between-timezones-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

It appears WooCommerce added a query parameter: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/pull/28132